# Probability Question (Union & Intersection)

Tags: probability

If we had two events $A_1$ and $A_2,$ which are finite or countable sequence of disjoint events. I know that
$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2),$ but what would happen if it was $P(A_1 \cap A_2)?$  Would it become $P(A_1)$ if $A_1$ is a larger subset of the sample space than $A_2,$ and vice versa?

Comment: I have edited your question for readability. Please check to make sure I have not changed your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to better answer the question: if $A_1\subset A_2$, then we have
$$A_1=A_1\cap A_2\subset A_2.$$
So taking the probability of the above equation,
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1)=\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)\leq \mathbb{P}(A_2).$$
So the most you can say is that $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)\leq \mathbb{P}(A_2).$
However, if we want to calculate instead $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)$, then using the fact that $A_1\subset A_2\implies A_1\cup A_2=A_2$, we would have
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_2).$$
For the case when $A_2\subset A_1$, the reasoning is entirely similar.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's OK to say $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B),$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (i.e., non-overlapping). In that case, $P(A \cap B) = P(\emptyset) = 0.$

If $P(A\cap B) > 0,$ then you must use the more general formula
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B).$$

Second, if $A \subset B,$ then $P(A\cup B) = P(B)$ and
$P(A\cap B) = P(A).$

Notice that $A \subset B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$ (that is all points in $A$ are also points in $B.$ By contrast, $A \subset B$ does not just mean that $B$ contains more points than $A.$ [You shouldn't read $A \subset B$ as "$A$ is smaller than $B$" or as "$B$ is bigger than $A$".]

*Example:* If $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B = \{b,c,d,e\},$
then $A$ is not a subset of $B.$ If $P(\{a\}) = 1/2$ and each of the other singleton sets has probability $1/10,$ then $P(A) = 0.7$ and $P(B) = 0.4.$